# How I assert my log message when the log is created by lombok

Tags: java, junit, lombok

I have the following code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyClass {

    private OtherClass otherClass;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(OtherClass otherClass) {
        this.otherClass = otherClass;
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            otherClass.execute();
        } catch (FeatureException exception) {
            log.warn(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I want do test to verify the log message.
I dont know how.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to verify the log message, that is probably a code smell. Can you elaborate on why you need to verify the log message?

Comment: @AlastorMoody Several use cases exist where a specific message is needed: the client requesting that this specific message is properly logged because some other tool expects it; a project manager that says I want 100% code coverage, including log statements, etc.

Comment: You can make a package private exception (PPE) which extends your FeatureException exception. This PPE has a logMessage() method which constructs the message you want without asking the calling code for a message. This PPE gives you the required log message you want and in your unit test you can check that the package private exception is thrown. From the public caller, they can still catch FeatureException. Does this solve your problem? If this works, then I can convert this comment into an answer so that you can accept it. If not, you can use assertEquals on the logMessage.

Comment: @AlastorMoody if someone says "upon this condition, I expect a WARNING to be logged", that's a requirement. Like any other requirement, it should be tested. I don't think that's a smell at all.

Comment: "upon this condition, I expect a WARNING to be logged" -> that's a fair use case. However OP is saying "pon this condition, I expect a WARNING to be logged with THIS EXACT message" -> devs should be able to tweak the message string to make their operations easier by adding additional info if needed.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire if there is some tooling that relies on a specific message being logged in a log file, then that is an indicator of a bad design. Logging is not 100% reliable, and system behavior should not be influenced by what is logged. There are other better architectures such as a message bus or a pub-sub model that is better than relying on a specific message in a log file. Similarly, 100% coverage does not need the message to be verified; just the fact that a message has been logged is enough to verify. ie "assertThat(log.warn).times(1)" or something similar is fine. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @AlastorMoody it is not unreasonable for the log requirement to include an explicit text. You don't know who might be reading the log and what their needs might be. Or their technical expertise. Or their budget to create more sophisticated solutions. It all depends on context, but a requirement that says "I need my log message to be exactly this" is not, on its own, indicative of any flaws.

Comment: Key word is "indicative". It it a code/design smell that warrants further thought? yes. Are there valid reasons why you might want to keep it that way? yes.  Code/design smells don't automatically indicate something is wrong. They just indicate that something might warrant a second look.

Answer (score 6):

The [SLF4J project recommends using](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html) the library [SLF4J Test](http://projects.lidalia.org.uk/slf4j-test/) for this use case.

In your case (using Hamcrest and Mockito as well):

```
public class MyClassTest {

  TestLogger logger = TestLoggerFactory.getTestLogger(MyClass.class);

  @Test
  public void testStart_loggingFailureMessage() {
    OtherClass otherClass = mock(OtherClass.class);
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(otherClass);

    when(otherClass.execute()).thenThrow(new FeatureException("Some text"));

    myClass.start();

    assertThat(logger.getLoggingEvents(), is(asList(LoggingEvent.warn("Some text"))));
  }

  @After
  public void clearLoggers() {
    TestLoggerFactory.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: `TestLoggerFactory.clear()` didn't seem to work for me, instead I had to use `logger.clearAll()`. Other than that, I believe this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: WHat is SLF4J Test, is that a Maven dependency?

Answer (score 0):

In case the other solution doesn't work for you, the one other choice: you could verify that the exception thrown by `otherClass.execute()`

A) sees a call to `getMessage()`

B) is catched (you could write one test that throws a runtime exception, which you would expect to hit your testcase; and a second test that throws a FeatureException ... which obviously should not make it to the test case).